# MediaSource.isTypeSupported not working in any browser for opus and caf

Tags: javascript, mime-types, media-source

Both of the following statements return false in both Chrome and Safari on my Mac OS. Yet, I can play the `.caf` container of an opus codec in Safari and I can play the `.opus` version in Chrome.

```js
const caf = MediaSource.isTypeSupported("audio/x-caf")
const opus = MediaSource.isTypeSupported("audio/ogg") // also tried "audio/opus"
```

I figure I must be using it wrong, but the API and list of codecs is quite limited. I used `ffmpeg` to generate the `.caf` and `.opus` files and when I look at the mime of them it shows application/octet-stream, even though they work as expected. So I can't use the files to determine the appropriate mime type.

I have no way of reliably distinguishing which file to download given that Apple products support `.caf` and non-Apple support `.opus`. I would like to refrain from using browser detection as it's not future proof or reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are certainly conflating the [`MediaSource.isTypeSupported()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/isTypeSupported) static method with the [`HTMLMediaElement#canPlayType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaytype) instance method.
These are different APIs and they'll return different results: [far less media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE) can be used with the [MediaSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource).

```js
const test = (type) => {
  console.log(type, new Audio().canPlayType(type) === "maybe");
};
test("audio/ogg"); // true in Chrome & Firefox
test("audio/x-caf"); // true in Safari
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes and it looks like "probably" is also a truthy option too, not just maybe.